# Display Jquery UI Dialog on current mouse position, bug in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, dialog

I am using Jquery  UI Dialog and its working fine in FF/Chrome/Opera but there's some issue with IE, I am having latest version of JQuery UI 1.8.5 and all the workarounds setting position:absolute etc are not working at all,

What I need is if my anchor tag is near to end of the browser window and there's not enough space for the ui dialog window to appear, the IE shows it down bringing the vertical bar, the user has to scroll a lil bit to see the ui dialog, this works fine in FF and chrome as mentioned earlier.

What I am looking at is some kind of work around to get over with this.

Here's the code thats opening the UI Dialog.

```
$("#opener").click(function() {

                    primaryDialog.dialog("open");

                return false;
            }).mouseover(function(event) {

                OnMouseOver(event);

            });

function OnMouseOver(event) {
            primaryDialog.dialog("option", "position", {
                my: "right top",
                at: "left bottom",
                of: event,
                offset: "10 10"
            });

        }
```

Comment: Could you link to an example implementation?

Comment: I have added a code sample as well